# Aggregate - $push an Array Expression in $group

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this aggregation pipeline:

```
{
    $project: {
        type: '$_id.type',
            datapoints: [
            {$multiply: ['$_id.timestamp', 1000]},
            '$count',
        ],
    },
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            type: '$type',
        },
        datapoints: {$push: '$datapoints'},
    },
},
```

... which brought me to a following question:
How could I possibly append/push/add/etc an array to `datapoints` in `$group` (what could let me avoid `$project` stage))?

If I try putting the same expression for `datapoints` in the `$project` under `$push` in the `$group` it gives me an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a fair point because you cannot just simply notate with "bracket" `[]` notation as available from MongoDB 3.2 into a [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/).

It's a bit of a hack, but you can basically wrap the expression with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) instead of using the `[]` notation:

```
{ "$group": {
  "_id": "$_id.type",
  "datapoints": {
    "$push": {
      "$map": {
        "input": [1],
        "in": [
          { "$multiply": ["$_id.timestamp", 1000] },
          "$count"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

Or even [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArray/) if your MongoDB supports it:

```
{ "$group": {
  "_id": "$_id.type",
  "datapoints": {
    "$push": {
      "$concatArrrays": [
        [
          { "$multiply": ["$_id.timestamp", 1000] },
          "$count"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}}
```

Or even [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/), which is actually probably the shortest to type, but it may not retain the order of elements if that is important to you:

```
{ "$group": {
  "_id": "$_id.type",
  "datapoints": {
    "$push": {
      "$setUnion": [
        [
          { "$multiply": ["$_id.timestamp", 1000] },
          "$count"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}}
```

Trying to simply do :

```
"datapoint": { "$push": [{ "$mulitply": [ ...
```

Will of course result in an error

> "errmsg" : "The $push accumulator is a unary operator",

And this sort of expression would be syntactically incorrect:

```
"datapoint": { "$push": { ["a"] }
```

So you need an "expression" of some sort which is "unary" and not "list based" and returns a BSON Array in result. The above operators cover those cases.